# How to set null object A in List<A>() C#

Tags: c#, list, collections

I have a class A like this:

```
public class Article
{
public Tag Test1 { get; set; } = new Tag();

}

public class Tag
{
public List<News> Test{ get; set; } = new List<News>();
}
```

I have a list like this:

```
News 1
   Tag 1{
             News 1
                   **Tag** {
                           News 1
                                Tag {....}
                           News 4
                                Tag {....}
                           News 5
                                Tag {....}
                       }
             News 4
                   Tag {....}
             News 5
                   Tag {....}
         }
News 2
News 3
```

I want to set null "**Tag**" 2nd on that list = null to avoid loop infinitely.
like this:

```
News 1
   Tag 1{
             News 1
                   Tag = null
             News 4
                   Tag = null
             News 5
                   Tag = null
          }
News 2
News 3
```

How to implement that.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You can remove the code which instantiates the list of News objects in the Tag class for your requirement

Comment: Properties which return a collection should never have a public setter imo.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, if you ran this now, you would get a out of memory exception or a stack overflow. i am guessing you want to mitigate this?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than checking for null, you really should be checking for `Test1.Count > 0` in your code. Then make sure no one adds any tags to the second level collections.